# Find matching strings in an array and re-write the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need your help.

I would like to be able to find a string in an array and based on as to whether or not the value has been found, to be able to mofiy the array accordingly.

```
var temp = ["BNI to John", "BNI to Smith", "BNI to Jane", "BNA to Craig", "BNA to David", "BNA to Michelle", "Media Call", "Report Paper", "Issue Paper"]
```

Some processing now....

```
If ("BNI to" matches what is in the array temp then) {

    Find the instance of "BNI to" and re-label to single name: Briefing Notes (Info)
}

If ("BNA to" matches what is in the array temp then) {

    Find the instance of "BNA to" and re-label to single name: Briefing Notes (Approval)

}
```

Re-write and output the same temp array to now read as:

```
var temp = ["Briefing Notes (Info)", "Briefing Notes (Approval)", "Media Call", "Report Paper", "Issue Paper"]
```

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: Exact match or loss one?

Comment: The problem is this seems like calculus to me. I don't know how to code this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `map` - replace what you need - then run a `reduce` to get rid of duplicates:

```
var temp = ["BNI to John", "BNI to Smith", "BNI to Jane", "BNA to Craig", "BNA to David", "BNA to Michelle", "Media Call", "Report Paper", "Issue Paper"];

var formatted = temp.map(function(str) {
    //Replace strings
    if (str.indexOf("BNI to") > -1) {
        return "Briefing Notes (Info)"
    } else if (str.indexOf("BNA to") > -1) {
        return "Briefing Notes (Approval)";
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}).reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
    //Filter duplicates
    if (p.indexOf(c) === -1) {
        p.push(c);
    }
    return p;
}, []);

//Output: ["Briefing Notes (Info)", "Briefing Notes (Approval)", "Media Call", "Report Paper", "Issue Paper"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of `map` and a `replace` should do the trick

```
var temp = ["BNI to John", "BNI to Smith", "BNI to Jane", "BNA to Craig", "BNA to David", "BNA to Michelle", "Media Call", "Report Paper", "Issue Paper"];
var result = temp.map(function(str) {return str.replace(/BNI/i, 'Briefing Notes (Info)');}).map(function(str) {return str.replace(/BNA/i, 'Briefing Notes (Approval)');});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = ["BNI to John", "BNI to Smith", "BNI to Jane", "BNA to Craig", "BNA to David", "BNA to Michelle", "Media Call", "Report Paper", "Issue Paper"];
temp.forEach(function(v, i) {
  temp[i] = v.replace(/^BNI to/, 'Briefing Notes (Info)')
             .replace(/^BNA to/, 'Briefing Notes (Approval)');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var temp = ["BNI to John", "BNI to Smith", "BNI to Jane", "BNA to Craig", "BNA to David", "BNA to Michelle", "Media Call", "Report Paper", "Issue Paper"];


        var BNIRegex = new RegExp("BNI to");
        var BNARegex = new RegExp("BNA to");

        var BNISubstituteString = "Briefing Notes (Info)";
        var BNASubstituteString = "Briefing Notes (Approval)";

        for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = temp[i].replace(BNIRegex, BNISubstituteString);
            temp[i] = temp[i].replace(BNARegex, BNASubstituteString);
            alert(temp[i]);
        }

    });
```

Comment: alert is just for verification purposes, remove it after testing ;)